# adb hangs when running scripts in debian chroot on android

Tags: android, linux, debian, adb

I'm trying to run some scripts under for testing binaries compiled for arm-android. To achieve this I have debian in chroot, bash script for my computer, for android shell and for chrooted debian itself. 
The problem is that after running this twice, adb hangs and it looks like only way to fix this is to reboot device. By hanging I mean that running adb shell, adb push or something like this has no effect, adb is not responding.

Also, if I keep adb shell open when it hangs, than even though I cannot connect new shell to my tablet, the old connection still works. I also observed that some services on android are being killed when adb stops responding. Any idea what may cause it and how can I debug it?

Script running on my computer:

```
adb shell "mount -o remount,rw /"
printf "Pushing android.sh to device... "
adb push android.sh /
adb shell "chmod 777 android.sh"
printf "Pushing debian.sh to device... "
adb push debian.sh /data/local/debian/
adb shell "chmod 777 /data/local/debian/debian.sh"
adb shell ./android.sh
printf "Fetching results from device... "
adb pull /data/result.log
cat result.log
```

android.sh :

```
mount -o bind /proc /data/local/debian/proc
mount -o bind /sys /data/local/debian/sys
mount -o bind /dev /data/local/debian/dev
mount -o bind /dev/pts /data/local/debian/dev/pts
mount -o remount,exec,dev,suid /data
mount -o bind /system /data/local/debian/system
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:$PATH
export HOME=/root
export SHELL=/bin/bash
chroot /data/local/debian ./debian.sh
```

and debian.sh:

```
cd /path-with-binaries
touch result.log
ctest my-tests > result.log
exit
```

Comment: a binary requiring a `chroot`ed Debian environment to run is not *compiled for arm-android*

Comment: In that case it is. Debian chroot is only needed to run tests for this binary, which are written in perl, as this binary works both under pure android and in debian chroot